# How do I get beta readers?

Tags: beta-readers

I wouldn't feel comfortable asking friends and family to read my work and getting their feedback. And I don't have an online platform to ask strangers.

What are my other options?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the social networks can be a good starting point
Subscribe to some niche Facebook groups that match your book genre and ask openly. Some might be happy to help

You can also call on Twitter on some hashtags (maybe on #WritingCommunity)

And if you have a budget for that, you will always find people if you pay. Maybe a freelance editor on a site like Upwork or else.

Good luck with your book !

Answer (score -1):

If you are not inclined to share with friends and family, how about work colleagues, your students or associates. Also submit to an Editor of a publication or Publishing house. That way you can get free technical review at no cost even if the work is rejected. You also won't have worries of your ideas being stolen, as may happen with some beta readers
Good luck.

Comment: Submitting to editors is not a reliable route to getting a free technical review. What you're more likely to get is a photocopied form rejection six months later.